# Trying to refresh json datas in python

Tags: python, json, selenium-webdriver

I enjoyed myself to create a bot in python that use reddit to get some magic arena code and try to redeem them automatically.

Unfortunately, the code works only if a reddit post is added before I run my script if a code is a post after I ran my script, my script doesn't get the new magic arena code (I don't know why because it tried to put a while condition on this in order to refresh the JSON data but didn't works, I mean the json data have been refreshed I suppose but the new magic arena code was not put in :

```
While True:
try:
    response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-agent': 'Chrome'})
    dict_json = response.json()
except:
    print("Error: Could not scrape subreddit!")
    driver.quit()
    exit()
time.sleep(10)
```

Below my entire script, if you can give me some help, would be nice, thanks.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import time
import json


# Replace <path_to_chromedriver> with the path to the Chromedriver executable
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Paul/Desktop/ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe')

# Go to the Magic: The Gathering Arena website
driver.get('https://magic.wizards.com/fr/mtgarena')

#breakpoint()

# Click the "ACCOUNTS" button
#try:
href_element = driver.find_element("xpath",'//a[@href="https://myaccounts.wizards.com/login"]')
href_element.click()

#Wait for the page to load
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
currentUrl = driver.current_url

# Find the username/email field and send the username to the input field.
uname = driver.find_element("name", "email") 
uname.send_keys("toto@hotmail.com")

# Find the password input field and send the password to the input field.
pword = driver.find_element("name", "password") 
pword.send_keys("toto")

BoutonSeConnecter = driver.find_element("xpath",'//button[normalize-space()="Se connecter"]')
BoutonSeConnecter.click();
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

# Scrape the Magic: The Gathering Arena subreddit for new code posts
url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/MagicArena/new/.json'

try:
    response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-agent': 'Chrome'})
    dict_json = response.json()
except:
    print("Error: Could not scrape subreddit!")
    driver.quit()
    exit()

json_data=json.dumps(dict_json)
json_obj = json.loads(json_data)

while True:
    for child in json_obj["data"]["children"]:
        code = child["data"]["selftext"]
        code_match = re.search(r'[A-Z0-9]{5}-[A-Z0-9]{5}-[A-Z0-9]{5}-[A-Z0-9]{5}-[A-Z0-9]{5}', code, re.IGNORECASE)
        if code_match:
            code = code_match.group(0)
            print(code)
                # Enter the code and click "Submit"
            try:
                input_field = driver.find_element("name", "code") 
                input_field.send_keys(code)
                BouttonEchangerCode = driver.find_element("xpath",'//button[normalize-space()="Échanger"]')
                BouttonEchangerCode.click();
            except:
                print(f"Error: Could not enter code {code}!")
                driver.quit()
                exit()
    time.sleep(10)
              
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Your current script (the second bit of code you pasted) only gets the API response once. You should add the bit that fetches the data from the API inside of your existing `while` loop (not a new/separate while loop), so it will hit the API over and over again and process the response.

Comment: Do you want the while loop to start 11 lines earlier with those 11 lines then properly indented?

Comment: Keep in mind: Reddit is going to return the same JSON (with any new posts) over and over again. You need a cache/database to store what events you already processed to avoid duplicates

Comment: You could also not use a python loop. And just run your code on a schedule on your OS (e.g Windows Scheduler)

Comment: @JNevill I tried to use a loop that included the datas fetched and i'm pretty sure the json was refreshed cause i did some tests but the new json data thatmatched with my regex was no put in my input field, i don't know why

Comment: @OneCricketeer You're righr, i didn't work on this point again, maybe i will store the tried codes in an array, i will figure it out this point but i try resolved my json datas refreshed before. I will try your schedule idea